# sql server for php 7.1.3 VS14

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

i'm trying to connect sqlsvr to php on Apache server. Here are the details:

**PHP Version 7.1.3**

**PHP Extension Build:**    API20160303,TS,VC14

i downloaded the sqlsvr driver that is compatible for php version 7.1 from here: github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases

I copied **php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll** and **php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll** into **C:\PHP\ext** directory.

Then i tried to locate the **php.ini** * file, but could only find the **php.ini-production** and **php.ini-development** in the C:\PHP directory.
I read on another thread that in php 7+, they removed php.ini and said to use the php.ini-production one.

Which i did, and added the the 2 extensions to php.ini-production:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll.
```

**Note *:** **Loaded Configuration File** is    (none) on my localhost site.

I then restarted the Apache server, but it doesn't seem to be connected to the sqlsvr (i used phpinfo() to check).

I can still connect to the site normally, nothing changes after trying to implement the sqlsvr

I also tried using the drivers from Microsofts official page, but no success

Any help would be much appreciated

**EDIT:**

So i sort of fixed it by doing the following:
I copied everything in php.ini-development and make a new file called php.ini (which didn't exist before). I modified it by un-commenting these lines:

```
extension=c:/php/ext/php_curl.dll
extension=c:/php/ext/php_gd2.dll
extension=c:/php/ext/php_intl.dll
extension=c:/php/ext/php_mbstring.dll
extension=c:/php/ext/php_mysqli.dll
extension=c:/php/ext/php_openssl.dll
extension=c:/php/ext/php_soap.dll
extension=c:/php/ext/php_xmlrpc.dll
```

And then i added these 2 lines:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
```

Now i restarted the Apache server, and how when i search for "sqlsrv", it's there. I also noticed that the **Loaded Configuration File** says   C:\PHP\php.ini instead of (none) now.

I then googled a way to test if a connection is established and found this code, which i put into the C:\Apache24\htdocs\ directory and called it connect.php;

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

I restart the apache server and go to localhost/connect.php and get this msg:

*"Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server for x64: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server for x64: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )"*

I go to the link, but the drivers only support up to php 7.0 (i have 7.1.3) But i try it anyways, and ofc it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Just saying you have no success is not helping us understand the problem.

Comment: @SeanLange No error msges, the site runs normally, nothing changes after trying implement the sqlsvr

Comment: Can you share your DSN with us?

Comment: What do mean nothing changes? I can't see your screen and have no idea what the issue is here. Give us some details so we know what the problem is.

Comment: @SeanLange So after i've done all the above, i go to my site (localhost) and i search for "sqlsvr" on the phpinfo page. I don't find any "sqlsvr", so that means it's not connected to sqlsvr. Th issue is, I've followed the instructions to install the sqlvr for php, but it is not working

Comment: @TimoSalola I'm just using "hppt://localhost" to access the site, i guess the DNS would be "127.0.0.1" by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem i was getting.

I just needed to download the ODBC driver from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50420